# Asp.net built-in request logger

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I wonder whether there is a built-in functionality in asp.net to log requests.  In the link below I can see an event that fires after Asp.net logging.  Google did not help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.logrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [`Trace.axd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wwh16c6c(v=vs.100).aspx) which keeps the request logging on a short period of time for debugging and analysis purposes.

Also, you have request logging capabilities in IIS, so not sure whether they are necessary in ASP.NET. There are some implementations on modules that can do request logging for you, but they are not built-in.